# React-table Filter component lost state on re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I'm using react and react table. In my react table, I have a custom filter component which user can choose from the dropdown which filters he will use for the column. It's like less than, equal to, etc.

here I found some example and tried to make the same: https://codesandbox.io/s/03403m5xzp

everything works well when I'm using client side filtering but when using server-side data, there I get some problem.

problem is an example. I choose from dropdown some filter type like equal-to and open the input for typing. When the user types something I make a request with the onFetchData method for sending this filter values to backend API to getting new data and setting it to the table. When I got new data I change my state and of course, changing state of my filterComponent and user need to choose again the filter type and open the input for typing again.

what I can do for keeping the state of my filter component in the last state while table data change?

here is my react table and filterComponent code.

```
class ParentComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    betweens: false,
    openTextBoxes: false
  };

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      pageSize: 15,
      data: [],
      pages: null,
      loading: false
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { data, pages, loading } = this.state;
    return (
      <ReactTable
        className="-striped -highlight"
        data={this.state.data}
        loading={this.state.loading}
        manual
        columns={columns}
        pages={this.state.pages}
        onFetchData={(state, instance) => {
          this.setState({ loading: true });
          let dataM = {
            pagesize: state.pageSize,
            page: state.page,
            sorts: JSON.stringify(state.sorted),
            filters: JSON.stringify(state.filtered)
          };
          axios
            .post(baseUrl + "v1/report/data/list", dataM, {
              headers: {
                Accept: "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
              }
            })
            .then(response => {
              this.setState({
                data: response.data.result,
                pages: Math.ceil(
                  response.data.record_count / this.state.pageSize
                ),
                loading: false
              });
              console.log(this.state.data);
            })
            .catch(error => {
              throw error;
            });
        }}
        filterable={true}
        resizable={true}
        sortable={true}
        defaultFilterMethod={filterCaseInsensitive}
        defaultPageSize={15}
        pageSizeOptions={[5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 50, 100]}
        getTdProps={onRowClick}
        minRows={undefined}
      />
    );
  }
}

class FilterInnerComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    betweens: false
  };
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      filterType: "All",
      filterValue: "",
      filterBetweenValue: "",
      openTextBox: true
    };

    this.changeFilterValue = this.changeFilterValue.bind(this);
  }

  changeFilterType(event) {
    console.log(event);
    // console.log(this.props.saveLastStateState)
    const filterType = event.target.value;
    selectedFilterTypeGlobal = filterType;
    this.setState({ filterType: filterType });
    const newValue = "";

    this.state.filterValue = newValue;
    this.state.filterBetweenValue = newValue;

    const newState = {
      ...this.state.filterType,
      ...this.state.filterValue,
      ...this.state.filterBetweenValue,
      filterType
    };

    if (filterType === "is-between" || filterType === "is-not-between") {
      this.state.betweens = true;
    } else {
      this.state.betweens = false;
    }
    if (filterType !== "All") {
      // this.props.getFilterinnerComponent()
      // this.state.openTextBox = true
      this.setState({
        openTextBox: true
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        openTextBox: true
      });
    }

    this.setState(newState);
    this.props.onChange(newState);
  }

  changeFilterValue(event) {
    const filterValue = event.target.value;
    selectedFilterValueGlobal = filterValue;
    parseFloat(filterValue).toFixed(2);
    const newState = {
      ...this.state,
      filterValue
    };
    this.setState(newState);
    this.props.onChange(newState);
  }

  changeBetweenFilterValue(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    }
    const filterBetweenValue = event.target.value;

    parseFloat(filterBetweenValue).toFixed(2);

    const newState = {
      ...this.state,
      filterBetweenValue
    };

    // Update local state
    this.setState(newState);
    // Fire the callback to alert React-Table of the new filter
    this.props.onChange(newState);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="filter">
        <SelectField
          onChange={evt => this.changeFilterType(evt)}
          style={{
            height: "30px",
            fontSize: "12px"
          }}
          value={this.state.filterType}
          autoWidth
        >
          <MenuItem value="All">All</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value="is-equal-to">Is Equal To</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value="is-not-equal-to">Is Not Equal To</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value="greater-than">Greater Than</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value="greater-than-or-equal-to">
            Greater Than Or Equal To
          </MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value="less-than">Less Than</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value="less-than-or-equal-to">
            Less Than Or Equal To
          </MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value="is-between">Is Between</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value="is-not-between">Is Not Between</MenuItem>
        </SelectField>
        {this.state.openTextBox ? (
          <TextField
            onChange={this.changeFilterValue}
            style={{
              width: "100%",
              height: "40px",
              float: "left",
              fontSize: "12px"
            }}
            type="text"
            value={this.state.filterValue}
          />
        ) : null}
        {this.state.betweens ? (
          <TextField
            onChange={evt => this.changeBetweenFilterValue(evt)}
            style={{
              width: "100%",
              height: "40px",
              float: "left",
              fontSize: "12px"
            }}
            type="text"
            value={this.state.filterBetweenValue}
          />
        ) : null}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you create a codepan for your question ?

Comment: unfortunately i can't because there is data from my job :(

Comment: @user3348410 use mock data

Comment: how i can use the mock data there is need to make a request to api for showing the changes of data i think

Comment: I think you are going about this the wrong way, you should make a request everytime a user uses the filter.

Comment: i make request in my onFetchData method it's mean there is already making request in when user use or change something. sorting, filtering etc

Comment: and `FilterInnerComponent` shouldn't have state, all state should be in parent compoent.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193335/discussion-between-junius-l-and-user3348410).

Comment: i put the state of child component to parent component and pass this state to parent component with prop. but how i can change this state from child to parent?

Comment: I have the same problem, I believe it is in conflict with some other library (in my case)

Comment: It helps me a lot: https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/faq#how-do-i-stop-my-table-state-from-automatically-resetting-when-my-data-changes